# Java : arraylist shows empty when it used to show null values

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I have a weird problem (please have in mind I reently started learning) the toString method ArrayList in let's say ArrayList(5) shows []

but [this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdpary-non-maven/org-netbeans-modules-editor-util/4.0/org/netbeans/modules/editor/util/GapList.java) whih is similar would show [null, null, null, null, null]

before ArrayList was showing nulls as well and I was happy and all was working fine (did i imagine it?) I need ArrayList to show me nulls like the link eample. Please help me

```html
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class testArray {

 
 public static void main (String[] arg){
  List myList = new ArrayList(5);
  System.out.print(myList);
 }
}
```

Edit: I think I didn't explain myself (I apologies). I DO want to create an empty list but I want null references instead of an empty list. I'm sure it's something dumb I'm not seeing

Edit2: I got it!...im sorry i wasnt able to be understood but this is what I wanted..

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    for (int i = 0; i<elem.length; i++) {
        sb.append(elems[i]);
            sb.append(", ");
    }
    return sb + "]\n" + elem.length+"\n";
}
```

I just had to oerride the tostring method so i would show the results as null :D thank you anyways!!! now i dont know how to close the post :P :P

Comment: use generic list List<Object> myList=new ArrayList<Object>(5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will initialize all your `list` elements to `null`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestArray {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(Collections.nCopies(5, null));
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

output: `[null, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: thank you Arun!. is there anyway to see the same result without atually adding "copying" the nulls?

Comment: You set the capacity to 5. The size is 0 until you add an element to it. This means every time I use, ArrayList, I need to fill stuff in. You are not using it if you don't "fill stuff in".

Comment: @Karol ArrayList collection object is different from arrays. You can get the same result using arrays - Object[] arr = new Object[5]; System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

Comment: @Karol - GapList is a custom implementation of the 
java.util.AbstractList (part of JDK), which is initializing the values of a list with default values (null for Object). However ArrayList does not do this. I hope you get it now

Comment: @Karol - Can you please accept my answer as it answered to your initial question? But later you wrote your own toString() to match your needs and this was not clear enough in the question